# XP virtual machine can search but cannot open any other link

Tags: virtual-machine

I set up an XP virtual machine on my MAC using a virtual box.

Interestingly, I can get onto google and search for something, but I cannot click on any of the results.

If I try to type on any other website, it does work.

Doing so results in a "The page cannot be displayed" error. Under settings -> advanced, I tried a few different Adapter Type, I have tried a few different settings but none of it works.

I tried to google this problem but cannot find any solutions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try a different browser.  Have you tried Chrome for XP?  

https://www.filepuma.com/download/google_chrome_32bit_49.0.2623.112-11045/

Comment: @John how do I download chrome on the VM if I cannot get onto internet?

Comment: You would need to download it on another machine, then onto a USB key and use the USB key to get it to the VM.  I tested my old version of Chrome on my XP Virtual Machine (using VMware as my virtualizing application)

Comment: @John let me try that. I only want to use the virtual machine for a software. I should just download the software onto the virtual machine using the way you described.

Comment: Make sure you set up USB passthrough on Virtual Box and the method should work fine.